# Sort MySQL records according to co-ordinates

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting

I have a **MySQL** Table where there are three columns: **lat**, **lon** and **ID**

Now as Input **I want user to give a pair of Lat & long**. In return, I want to show the **sorted rows from closest to farthest**.

Now, one solution of this problem is, **fetch all entries** in an array, make a **temp array**, calculate distance for each item using **haversine** formula, push to the temp array, and finally perform any sorting algorithm on that array.

But, this operation is heavy and I want a better solution. Is there any?

P.S: I am using PHP script.

Comment: The existing solution looks good to me. You might like to provide a bounding box as part of a WHERE clause, to filter out coordinates that are clearly outside the scope of calculation

Comment: you can use the haversine formula directly in sql and sorting the resulting values ..

Answer (score 1):

short answer: NO.

Long answer: maybe.  IF you are working within a given and VERY limited radius, you can simplify things by y establishing a fixed value for each tenth of a degree in lat and in lng and apply the hypothenuse (square root of [delta lat squared + delta lng squared]).

But this will work only for points that are quite close to your center point.